# How can CoreData NSManagedObject != NIL but does not contain any data (data: <fault>)?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I encountered a pretty weird problem while *using CoreData*. I got an extension which saves and **gets the active Profile** saved in CoreData by **using UserDefaults** to store the **active Profile ObjectID**.

```swift
extension NSPersistentContainer {
    private var managedObjectIDKey: String {
        return "activeUserObjectID"
    }

    var activeUser: Profile? {
        get {
            guard let url = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: managedObjectIDKey) else {
                return nil
            }

            guard let managedObjectID = persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: url) else {
                return nil
            }

            return viewContext.object(with: managedObjectID) as? Profile
        }
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: managedObjectIDKey)
                return
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.objectID.uriRepresentation(), forKey: managedObjectIDKey)
        }
    }
}
```

This whole think just works fine most of the time but then I found an very weird bug. The user is able to **delete profiles** *(BUT NOT THE CURRENT ACTIVE ONE!)*

The bug is the following: As soon as I delete e.g. `Profile 2` while `Profile 1` is activated, as soon as the deletion is finished `Profile 1` is not activated anymore.

When trying to print out the activeUser variable it returns only **data: fault** instead of **data: {*all the data*}**. See the screenshot below:

[image]

The first line is printed before deleting `Profile 2`, the second line is printed directly after deleting the profile and the third line is printed after activating a profile again.

*I have no idea what could cause this bug and spend a lot of time into finding this bug but haven't been succesful.*

If you have any idea please let me now. Does maybe the ObjectID of all NSManagedObjects change after deleting one? Or is there anything else I didn't think of?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @Arkku yes that's right and I didn't see it. Let me check this out for a second.

Comment: @Arkku I'm so bad;) The Delete button was linked to the activate() and delete() method. So the profile got activated and then deleted. Feel free to publish your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object id of the object showing `<fault>` is different from the other two. If I understood correctly, your intent was to keep the the same profile active all the time, but this doesn't seem to be the case, i.e., something is activating a different profile.